# jQuery how to use a parent() variable in another selector find() or children() required?

Tags: jquery, variables, find, selector, parent

I have looked at many posts here, none of them had an example of what I am looking to do...

I have a variable.. that is a selector to my parent() DOM element.

```
var targetCase = $(this).parent();
```

I have this other selector (current saved as a variable, but does NOT container the parent variable above:

```
var mapInfoRating = $("input[name='map_info']:checked").val();
```

What is the correct syntax to use the parent selector variable in a new selector that is targeting the map_info input value?

I eventually stumbled upon this, and its working, but is this best approach?

```
targetCase.find("input[name='map_info']:checked").val();
```

ie: using the 'find()' function?

I mean if the parent() is defined.. I shouldnt need to use 'find()' ...right? (as I have the name)...  but I cant figure it out without using find()?

Is there a more direct way to use this?  Od I need to use find() or children() as that is just how the syntax dictates?

To be clear, find() does seem to be working.

Comment: `targetCase` is not a selector.  It is a jQuery object containing the parent element.  And since it's a jQuery object, all jQuery methods can be used off of it, which includes `find()`.  And given that it works for you, I'm not sure why you asked the question.

Comment: It's very hard to tell you what to use without seeing your html code

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/ and the subsequent http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/working-with-selections/ provide some readable intro documentation into using selectors with jquery

Comment: @Taplar I asked becuase I wasnt clear if find() was REQUIRED.. I couldnt get it to work by just using the parent() variable and  input[name=xx]:checked.

Also.. would children() be better if some kind of method IS required?

Comment: `find()` and `children()` are just dom traversal methods.  They are only required if your logic requires them.  If your jQuery object is a parent of some element you need to get to, if it is an immediate child of that element, you could use `children()` to get it.  If it is not an immediate child, or even if it is, you could use `find()`.  The requirement is entirely around the structure of your DOM and the context by which you are starting at.

Comment: An argument between using `find()` vs `children()` in the context where both would result in the same element is primarily an opinionated one, revolving around if the programmer feels that using `children()` applies too strong of a logical relationship between the elements, where as `find()` is less strict.  But that is an opinionated issue, and if both work in a given situation, use which ever you like better.

Comment: ok.. last question, so I am clear.. how can one go about NOT using the find() or children() method then?  I couldnt get the syntax to work (using the name of the input field.. along with the parent() variable)..

Comment: The only way to not use `find()` or `children()` is to already have a reference to the element; either by finding it with a `$(selector)` or already having a reference to it and turning it into a jQuery object such as you did above with your `$(this)`